# Most efficient way to parse a dynamic List of int from string

Tags: c#, list

Out of curiosity, is there a faster/more efficient way to parse a dynamic list of `int`s from a `string`?

Currently I have this, and it works absolutely fine; I was just thinking there might be a better way as this seems a little overly complex for something so simple.

```
public static void Send(string providerIDList)
{
String[] providerIDArray = providerIDList.Split('|');
var providerIDs = new List<int>();
for (int counter = 0; counter < providerIDArray.Count(); counter++)
{
     providerIDs.Add(int.Parse(providerIDArray[counter].ToString()));
}
//do some stuff with the parsed list of int
```

Edit: Perhaps I should have said a **more simple** way to parse out my list from the string.  But since the original question did state **faster and more efficient** the chosen answer will reflect that.

Comment: Why does it have to be the most efficient?  Are you doing this millions of times a day?

Comment: Nope, I was honestly just curious.  I want to form good habits of doing things the most efficient way.

Comment: Then I would recommend finding the most readable and maintainable way.

Comment: You could shorten it up using a single line of LINQ: `var providerIds = providerIDList.Split('|').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();`, but it wouldn't perform any better. The one micro-optimizing thing I see is replace `providerIDArray.Count()` with `providerIDArray.Length` - using the native array length will save one hop in your stack trace, might save you a microsecond or so. And your `ToString()` is redundant since it's already a string, so that can go away.

Comment: It's unclear what your goal is. There are definitely faster ways of parsing numbers, but the code is a lot more complex. Is that what you want? There is simpler ways to write the code, but that is not faster. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Jfabs: Doing things the most efficient way possible *isn't* a good habit. Adopting an approach of defining performance acceptance criteria, writing the simplest/most maintainable working code and then testing it against those criteria, and rewriting for performance in *targeted* ways... that's an good habit.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Definitely noted!  I am still glad I asked though, feedback from the SO community is always welcome.

Comment: @Jfabs - If you actually want a fast/efficient solution check my answer, otherwise use linq and it'll be prettier and easier to mangle (maintain) later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's definitely a better way. Use LINQ:

```
var providerIDs = providerIDList.Split('|')
                                .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
                                .ToList();
```

Or using a method group conversion instead of a lambda expression:

```
var providerIDs = providerIDList.Split('|')
                                .Select(int.Parse)
                                .ToList();
```

This is *not* the most efficient way it can be done, but it's quite possibly the simplest. It's about as efficient as your approach - though that could be made slightly more efficient fairly easily, e.g. giving the `List` an initial capacity.

The difference in performance is likely to be irrelevant, so I'd stick with this simple code until you've got evidence that it's a bottleneck.

Note that if you don't need a `List<int>` - if you just need something you can iterate over once - you can kill the `ToList` call and use `providerIDs` as an `IEnumerable<int>`.

EDIT: If we're in the efficiency business, then here's an adaptation of the `ForEachChar` method, to avoid using `int.Parse`:

```
public static List<int> ForEachCharManualParse(string s, char delim)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    int tmp = 0;
    foreach(char x in s)
    {
        if(x == delim)
        {
            result.Add(tmp);
            tmp = 0;
        } 
        else if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')
        {
            tmp = tmp * 10 + x - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input: " + s);
        }
    }
    result.Add(tmp);
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

- This will add zeroes for any consecutive delimiters, or a delimiter at the start or end
- It doesn't handle negative numbers
- It doesn't check for overflow
- As noted in comments, using a `switch` statement instead of the `x >= '0' && x <= '9'` can improve the performance further (by about 10-15%)

If none of those are a problem for you, it's about 7x faster than `ForEachChar` on my machine:

```
ListSize 1000 : StringLen 10434
ForEachChar1000 Time : 00:00:02.1536651
ForEachCharManualParse1000 Time : 00:00:00.2760543

ListSize 100000 : StringLen 1048421
ForEachChar100000 Time : 00:00:02.2169482
ForEachCharManualParse100000 Time : 00:00:00.3087568

ListSize 10000000 : StringLen 104829611
ForEachChar10000000 Time : 00:00:22.0803706
ForEachCharManualParse10000000 Time : 00:00:03.1206769
```

The limitations can be worked around, but I haven't bothered... let me know if they're significant concerns for you.

Comment: "Better"? It that "better" in the terms the OP was asking for ("faster/more efficient"), or is it "better" in terms of being more readable?

Comment: @Steve: Better in terms of readability. Have added a note about performance.

Comment: Very cool regardless, seems like I should look into learning more about LINQ the more time I spend on SO.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jfabs: Yes, if you're not already thoroughly indoctrinated into LINQ, it's *well* worth learning more :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'll definitely take that advice.  And thank you again for the note about the `IEnumerable<int>` vs `List<int>`.  I'll keep that in mind

Comment: So this is definitely a more readable and simpler way, however I did feel the need to change the answer to @LastCoder as his actually provides evidence of being _faster_ or _more efficient_ whereas this is more readable which is perfectly fine with me.  Both are excellent answers

Comment: @Jfabs: This is the problem with asking two different questions as if they were one - you asked about efficient code, and then you complained that your current code was too complex. The now-accepted answer is *more* complex (though more efficient) - my answer is *less* complex (but only about as efficient). You really need to decide between those two concerns, and ask questions appropriately.

Comment: @Jfabs: In the name of completeness, I've added another option which is very significantly faster than the currently accepted answer :)

Comment: As a quick experiment, I tried changing from ifs to case statements (hard-coding the delim).  This ran slower, possibly due to horrible branch prediction.  However, changing it to use one one case block for all of the numbers (i.e., `case '0': case '1': ... case '9': tmp = tmp * 10 + x - '0';break;`), made it run about 15% faster than your solution.  I imagine this is because case statements are cheaper than the >= and <= comparison, but it's equally likely that I messed something up.  Since you didn't post your benchmarking code, I'll leave it to you to reproduce my benchmark (or not).

Comment: @Brian: I just used the same benchmarking code as Jfabs. Will add a note in my answer.

Comment: I tried running his benchmark on my case-based variation of your answer.  It pretty consistently dropped the running time by about 15%.  I don't think the case variation is more difficult to understand, but it is much more verbose and forces the delimiter to be hard-coded.  I'm sure others could come up more absurd efficiency optimizations.  For example, using unsafe code to access the underlying char array of the string not only might make the code run faster but also might make your coworkers run faster (away from your code).

Comment: @Brian: I found it improved things even *without* putting the delimiter as a constant - doing it after that bit. But I've also found that converting `x` to an `int` in one place and using that `int` for the subsequent operations helped a bit... not quite as much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like any of the answers so far. So to actually answer the question the OP posed "fastest/most efficient" String.Split with Int.Parse, I wrote and tested some code.

Using Mono on an Intel 3770k.

I found that using String.Split + IEnum.Select is not the fastest (maybe the prettiest) solution. In fact it's the slowest.

**Here's some benchmark results**

```
ListSize 1000 : StringLen 10468 
SplitForEach1000 Time : 00:00:02.8704048 
SplitSelect1000 Time : 00:00:02.9134658 
ForEachChar1000 Time : 00:00:01.8254438 
SplitParallelSelectr1000 Time : 00:00:07.5421146 
ForParallelForEachChar1000 Time : 00:00:05.3534218

ListSize 100000 : StringLen 1048233 
SplitForEach100000 Time : 00:00:01.9500846 
SplitSelect100000 Time : 00:00:02.2662606 
ForEachChar100000 Time : 00:00:01.2554577 
SplitParallelSelectr100000 Time : 00:00:02.6509969 
ForParallelForEachChar100000 Time : 00:00:01.5842131

ListSize 10000000 : StringLen 104824707 
SplitForEach10000000 Time : 00:00:18.2658261 
SplitSelect10000000 Time : 00:00:20.6043874 
ForEachChar10000000 Time : 00:00:10.0555613 
SplitParallelSelectr10000000 Time : 00:00:18.1908017 
ForParallelForEachChar10000000 Time : 00:00:08.6756213
```

**Here's the code to get the benchmark results**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FastStringSplit
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            char delim = ':';
            int[] sizes = new int[]{1000, 100000, 10000000 };
            int[] iters = new int[]{10000, 100, 10};
            Stopwatch sw;

            List<int> list, result = new List<int>();
            string str;
            for(int s=0; s<sizes.Length; s++) {
                list = new List<int>(sizes[s]);
                for(int i=0; i<sizes[s]; i++)
                    list.Add (rnd.Next());
                str = string.Join(":", list);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nListSize {0} : StringLen {1}", sizes[s], str.Length));
                ////
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                for(int i=0; i<iters[s]; i++) {
                    sw.Start();
                    result = SplitForEach(str, delim);
                    sw.Stop();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("SplitForEach" + result.Count + " Time : " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                ////
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                for(int i=0; i<iters[s]; i++) {
                    sw.Start();
                    result = SplitSelect(str, delim);
                    sw.Stop();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("SplitSelect" + result.Count + " Time : " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                ////
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                for(int i=0; i<iters[s]; i++) {
                    sw.Start();
                    result = ForEachChar(str, delim);
                    sw.Stop();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("ForEachChar" + result.Count + " Time : " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                ////
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                for(int i=0; i<iters[s]; i++) {
                    sw.Start();
                    result = SplitParallelSelect(str, delim);
                    sw.Stop();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("SplitParallelSelectr" + result.Count + " Time : " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
                ////
                sw = new Stopwatch();
                for(int i=0; i<iters[s]; i++) {
                    sw.Start();
                    result = ForParallelForEachChar(str, delim);
                    sw.Stop();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("ForParallelForEachChar" + result.Count + " Time : " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
            }
        }
        public static List<int> SplitForEach(string s, char delim) {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            foreach(string x in s.Split(delim))
                result.Add(int.Parse (x));
            return result;
        }
        public static List<int> SplitSelect(string s, char delim) {
            return s.Split(delim)
                .Select(int.Parse)
                    .ToList();
        }
        public static List<int> ForEachChar(string s, char delim) {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;
            foreach(char x in s) {
                if(x == delim || end == s.Length - 1) {
                    if(end == s.Length - 1)
                        end++;
                    result.Add(int.Parse (s.Substring(start, end-start)));
                    start = end + 1;
                }
                end++;
            }
            return result;
        }
        public static List<int> SplitParallelSelect(string s, char delim) {
            return s.Split(delim)
                .AsParallel()
                    .Select(int.Parse)
                        .ToList();
        }
        public static int NumOfThreads = Environment.ProcessorCount > 2 ? Environment.ProcessorCount : 2;
        public static List<int> ForParallelForEachChar(string s, char delim) {
            int chunkSize = (s.Length / NumOfThreads) + 1;
            ConcurrentBag<int> result = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            int[] chunks = new int[NumOfThreads+1];
            Task[] tasks = new Task[NumOfThreads];
            for(int x=0; x<NumOfThreads; x++) {
                int next = chunks[x] + chunkSize;
                while(next < s.Length) {
                    if(s[next] == delim)
                        break;
                    next++;
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(next);
                chunks[x+1] = Math.Min(next, s.Length);
                tasks[x] = Task.Factory.StartNew((o) => {
                    int chunkId = (int)o;
                    int start = chunks[chunkId];
                    int end = chunks[chunkId + 1];
                    if(start >= s.Length)
                        return;
                    if(s[start] == delim)
                        start++;
                    //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", start, end));
                    for(int i = start; i<end; i++) {
                        if(s[i] == delim || i == end-1) {
                            if(i == end-1) 
                                i++;
                            result.Add(int.Parse (s.Substring(start, i-start)));
                            start = i + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }, x);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here's the function I recommend**

```
        public static List<int> ForEachChar(string s, char delim) {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            int start = 0;
            int end = 0;
            foreach(char x in s) {
                if(x == delim || end == s.Length - 1) {
                    if(end == s.Length - 1)
                        end++;
                    result.Add(int.Parse (s.Substring(start, end-start)));
                    start = end + 1;
                }
                end++;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**Why it's faster?**

It doesn't split the string into an array first. It does the splitting and parsing at the same time so there is no added overhead of iterating over the string to split it and then iterating over the array to parse it.

I also threw in a parallel-ized version using tasks, but it is only faster in the case with very large strings.

Comment: I definitely appreciate this response especially with its full analysis!  And considering my original title and original request I will be changing my accepted answer to this as it does fit the original bill.  However, like I edited in, what I should have said was **more simple** and **more readable**.  Regardless, thanks!

Comment: @Jfabs - I thought it was an interesting question. The 2x speedup over the pretty Linq version was a little surprising as well. This answer was purely for my own curiosity; if you don't require speed than pretty and maintainable will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This appears cleaner:

```
var providerIDs = providerIDList.Split('|').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

if you really want to know the most efficent way, then use unsafe code, define char pointer from string, iterate all chars incrementing char pointer, buffer read chars until the next '|', convert buffered chars to int32. if you want to be really fast then do it manually (begin with last char, substruct value of '0' char, multiply it 10, 100, 1000... accoring to iteration variable, then add it to the sum variable. i dont have time to write code but hopefully you get the idea